# Can't access all administrator menus and menu labels have weird symbols

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, administrator, menu, migration

I am trying to migrate a Joomla website from server A to my server B. Everything seems to be working fine, except my administrator side / backend has the following issues:

- I am not able to access all my admin menus - every time that I press on a menu I get `#`
- My menu item labels show funny symbols as seen on the below screen shot

[image]

> **Warning**
> Your PHP version, 5.6.38, is only receiving fixes at this time from the PHP project. This means your PHP version will soon no longer be supported. We recommend planning to upgrade to a newer PHP version before it reaches end of support on 2018-10-01. Joomla will be faster and more secure if you upgrade to a newer PHP version (PHP 7.x is recommended). Please contact your host for upgrade instructions.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and the Joomla cache to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Potentially related: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/16640/12352 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/20851880/2943403 and https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=930671

Answer (score 2):

As one commenter suggested, try clearing your browser cache and the Joomla cache and see if that fixes the problem (also try restarting your browser and restart your Internet modem). If that doesn't fix the problem, then open the Chrome console when in the backend (press F12 and then click on console in your browser), and see which files are returning a 404. Once you make a list of these files, check their permissions (and their parent folders' permissions) and ensure that they can be read by the Apache server. If that also doesn't work, then re-upload these files.

Note that when you move a website from one server to another, you might have transient issues like this one which will resolve themselves once DNS propagation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

**This problem occurs due to a change in the PHP version in the server to (7.3 or 7.4)** Therefore, you need to change the version to less than that, for example **(7.0).**

**Other suggestion:** change .htaccess make hash (#) for all lines.. see this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=157&v=PPOQSyjEAig)

**If the problem is not resolved**, you need to download a backup copy in your laptop, update the Joomla version, and then upload it again ..so that it is compatible with the new PHP version.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour].